# Error Message: Call to undefined method CI_DB_mysqli_result::results()

Tags: php, codeigniter-3

I am new to CodeIgniter and experiencing the following error after connecting the db . It is really great if some one can help me. I checked previous answers in the StackOverflow but none helped me.

Below is the controller code

```
    <?php

defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Welcome extends MY_Controller {

    public function index() {
        $this->load->view('home');
    }

    public function adminRegister() {
        //loading teh queries model 
        $this->load->model('queries');
        //Calling the getRoles function inside the roles
        $roles = $this->queries->getRoles();
        print_r($roles);
        exit();
        $this->load->view('register');
    }

    public function login() {
        echo 'login';
    }
}
```

Model code

```
    <?php
//Details of queries whicha re used to interact with teh database

class Queries extends CI_Model {
//Created a function with the name getRoles  
    public function getRoles() {
        //Fetch the reocrds from the table
        $roles = $this->db->get('tbl_roles');
        if ($roles->num_rows() > 0) {
            return $roles->results();
        }
    }

}

?>
```

Currently not using the data coming from controller. Any help will be highly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no **results** it should be **result**

Refer [CI Doc](https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/results.html)

```
class Queries extends CI_Model {
    //Created a function with the name getRoles  
        public function getRoles() {
            //Fetch the reocrds from the table
            $roles = $this->db->get('tbl_roles');
            if ($roles->num_rows() > 0) {
                return $roles->result();
            }
        }

    }
```

Comment: Isn't this just a typo then?

Comment: @NigelRen yes, but if anyone have same then they can refer thats why